# How to access input values in a modal by using function outside the click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I created a modal dialog in my page and it contains a form. I want to have an AJAX process after clicking a button. Now my problem is I can't get the input values in my modal.

Here's my code:

My code in the onclick

```
$('.order_concern').on('click', function(){

    var order_id = $(this).data('order-id');
    var product_id = $(this).data('product-id');
    var product_name = $(this).data('product-name');
    var seller_id = $(this).data('seller-id');
    var seller_name = $(this).data('seller-name');
    var customer_id = <?php echo $customer_id; ?>

    var     concern_form  = '<div class="row">';
            concern_form += '   <div class="form-group">';
            concern_form += '       <label>Product</label>';
            concern_form += '       <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="width: 97%" name="response_product" value="' + product_name + '" READONLY />';
            concern_form += '   </div>';
            concern_form += '</div>';

            concern_form += '<div class="row">';
            concern_form += '   <div class="form-group">';
            concern_form += '       <label>Seller Name</label>';
            concern_form += '       <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="width: 97%" name="response_seller_name" value="' + seller_name + '" READONLY />';
            concern_form += '   </div>';
            concern_form += '</div>';

            concern_form += '<div class="row">';
            concern_form += '   <div class="form-group">';
            concern_form += '       <label>Select Concern</label>';
            concern_form += '       <select class="form-control" style="width: 97%" name="response_status">';
            concern_form += '           <option value="">--  Select Concern --</option>';
            concern_form += '           <option value="Product not received">Product not received</option>';
            concern_form += '           <option value="Product has defect">Product has defect</option>';
            concern_form += '           <option value="Product did not reached the quantity of the order">Product did not reached the quantity of the order</option>';
            concern_form += '           <option value="Invalid product(request to replace)">Invalid product(request to replace)</option>';
            concern_form += '           <option value="Request to cancel"></option>';
            concern_form += '       </select>';
            concern_form += '   </div>';
            concern_form += '</div>';

            concern_form += '<div class="row">';
            concern_form += '   <div class="form-group">';
            concern_form += '       <label>Message to seller</label>';
            concern_form += '       <textarea class="form-control" style="width: 97%" name="response_message"></textarea>';
            concern_form += '   </div>';
            concern_form += '</div>';

            concern_form += '<div class="row">';
            concern_form += '   <div class="form-group">';
            concern_form += '       <label class="required response_alert"></label>';
            concern_form += '   </div>';
            concern_form += '</div>';

    var     concern_buttons  = '<input type="button" class="btn-jpmall" value="Send" onClick="sendConcernStatus(' + order_id + ', ' + product_id + ', ' + customer_id + ')" /> ';
            concern_buttons += '<input type="button" class="btn-jpmall-inverse"  data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel" />';

    $('.modal_concern .modal-title').text('Inform Seller');
    $('.modal_concern .message').html(concern_form);
    $('.modal_concern .modal_buttons').html(concern_buttons);
    $('.modal_concern').modal('show');

});
```

Now I want to get the value in this input:

```
concern_form += '       <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="width: 97%" name="response_product" value="' + product_name + '" READONLY />';
```

Then after I click the button inside the modal:

```
var concern_buttons  = '<input type="button" class="btn-jpmall" value="Send" onClick="sendConcernStatus(' + order_id + ', ' + product_id + ', ' + customer_id + ')" /> ';
```

I will access this function:

```
function sendConcernStatus(order_id, product_id, customer_id) {

    var container = $('.modal concern .message');
    var product_name =$('.modal concern .modal-content .modal-body .mesage input[name=response_product]').val();

    console.log(product_name);
}
```

But I got an `undefined` value.

Comment: `.mesage input` should be `.message input`....

Comment: Ok thanks I already change but still undefined

Comment: `var product_name = $('input[name=response_product]').val();`

Answer (score 3):

You have some typos `.mesage` should be `.message`  and
`.modal concern` should be `.modal_concern`

In any case I guess that you can go directly by-`name`

```
function sendConcernStatus( /*arguments here*/ ) {
    var product_name = $('.modal_concern').find('input[name="response_product"]').val();
    console.log(product_name); // works
}
```

Also, to leverage your JS, use `\n\` to split string newlines:

```
var concern_form  = '<div class="row">\n\
  <div class="form-group">\n\
    <label>Product</label>\n\
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="width: 97%" name="response_product" value="' + product_name + '" READONLY />\n\
   </div>\n\
</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks it works. By the way the one you said in the leverage. Is it much more advisable to use than the one I used?

Comment: @Jerielle as you prefer. I always do it the way I've shown you. Simpler, cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Like i said before and since the names should be unique, you can use a direct approach:

```
var product_name = $('input[name="response_product"]').val();
console.log(product_name);
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, please look at the comment in the OP question ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, the fact that you edited your answer and adapt your code to match my comment...well, i don't want to fight...@Jerielle should choose your answer as correct :)

Comment: Then undo it and explain the OP, why is a faster selector(totally right, is faster)...like i said before, your answer should be mark as correct...and i was helping the OP since the begining(also correct), sorry if my answer bothers you :)